# MySQL Workbench don't show the result grid when I execute a script

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

When I execute a script, MySQL Workbench don't show up the result grid for me to view all records. Like a below picture:

My MySQL Workbench is in version 6.3.9.

[MySQL Workbench](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hfl0l.png)

MySQL Workbench of my friends can show like this:

[My friend's MySQL Workbench](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c66pt.png)

Please help me !

Comment: 0 rows returned vs 1 row returned. Your table is empty.

Comment: It still dont show the result grid when I have more than 1 record. I have just update the post with picture has more than 1 record.

Comment: graphic still shows "0 row(s) returned" -- your table is empty.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hfl0l.png

Comment: are you on mac osx? https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=87714

Answer (score 15):

After executing the query that you want (ex: SELECT * FROM table) execute the EXPLAIN command

[image: execute command]

It will open a new panel and on the right side you can find the option to open the Result Grid.

[image: result grid]

Comment: Oh my gosh. Thank you I finally found this post. 100000 people are out there "successfully" closing WOrkbench in order to get their tables to show up instead of using this button. Lordy

Answer (score 5):

UPDATE: Mysqlworkbench 6.3.10 has been released. If you have this problem, you should get the official update.

========================

Looks like this is a known bug in MySQL Workbench on High Sierra, the latest Mac OS.

It is fixed in the next version 6.3.10, but as of 10/17/17 that isn't available.

See the bug report here:

http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=87714

From the bug report, there is a user build that addresses the issue:

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B2fTesDcrHzVRGVFWEdILWpuaEE?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and restart of the program helped me on  Mysql workbench 8.0 CE

Comment: That is not an answer

Comment: Yes, this version 8.0 of MySQL Workbench remains with this bug and the solution of @ifhy showed the grid back.

Comment: Yes, restarting fixed it for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue as well. In my case since I don't have internet on my house, I will enter my workaround as answer (just in case others have the same scenario as mine). My workaround is **to close and re-open the MySQL Workbench as my workaround** to fix the issue.

I Agree to Garr Godfrey since it is a known bug, you need to update your workbench. Updating the MySQL Workbench will permanently fix this issue. :)